# Struts2 jQuery plugin + How Do call ajax from javascript for tag select

Tags: javascript, select, struts2, struts2-jquery

The next code works good..

```
           <s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsonsample"/> 
            <sj:select 
                href="%{remoteurl}" 
                id="language" 
                onChangeTopics="reloadsecondlist" 
                name="language" 
                list="languageObjList" 
                listKey="myKey" 
                listValue="myValue" 
                emptyOption="true" 
                headerKey="-1" 
                headerValue="Please Select a Language"
                />
```

but: these code load with `<s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsonsample"/>` as soon load the page... I want execute the action from javascript like this:

```
<div id="result" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;">Click me!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#result").click(function() {

Here ... How execute the action "jsonsample"? and refresh in the select "language"
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: What is #result, a button ? What do you want to achieve and why ?

Comment: result is only a id of a div, this line is up. that div has a event click, that event click should execute an action with name "jsonsample", that action return a object JSON. the question was how do ajax call and then how update this JSON return in the sj:select.

Answer (score 0):

There is `reloadTopics` attribute in `<sj:select>` tag which takes a comma delimited list of topics that will cause it to reload. Add it to your `<sj:select>` tag and publish event using `publish` function.

```
<sj:select ... reloadTopics="reloadSelect"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#result").click(function() {
      $.publish("reloadSelect");
    });
  });
</script>
```