# how to prevent submit on onclicktopics

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, struts, struts2-jquery

I have the following codes, saveBt, should not submit when user selects cancel on confirm however it seems it still submits cause I have onClickTopics, I need this onclicktopics to reload a struts jquery grid. Any workarounds?

```
$("#saveBt").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                if($('#Form').valid()){
                    if (confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

<sj:a id="saveBt" onClickTopics="reloadGrid" name="saveChannel" value="saveChannel">Save</sj:a>
```

UPDATE: Need onClicks to reload grid via :

```
<sj:a id="saveBt" onClickTopics="reloadGrid" name="save" value="save">Save</sj:a>
<sjg:grid id="gridTable"  reloadTopics="reloadGrid" resizable="true"
                     autowidth="true">
```

Comment: So don't use `onClickTopics`.

Comment: need it as it is tied to struts grid

Comment: Use `.click` or `onClickTopics`. Why do you need both? You can reload your grid from `.click` also.

Comment: How to reload grid from .click? updated question with grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with:

```
    function validator() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to save?")) {
            $("#Form").submit();
            $("#refresh_gridTable").click();
        }
    }

<sj:a id="saveBt" onclick="return validator();">Save</sj:a>
```

Struts jquery Grid creates a refresh button via setting : `navigatorRefresh="true"`  just had to click it after submit.

Comment: You can publish topic to reload grid.

Answer (score 0):

try this, delegate method.

```
$(document).on('click','#saveBt', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if($('#Form').valid()){
    if (confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: still the same, still submits, through the onclicktopics

Answer (score 0):

Reload the grid after the click event fire.That is inside the binding method. Then call the event.preventDefault after you reload the grid.

The point is not to bubble the event after the grid reload. If it's that what you mean.

Comment: how to invoke reload grid inside jquery event? onClickTopics currently maps to reloadTopics in my code.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266513/struts2-jquery-plugin-how-do-call-ajax-from-javascript-for-tag-select